# How to enable reporting in Jmeter Maven Plugin?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

With the Jmeter Maven Plugin, from version 1.5 onwards, reporting is disabled by default, as per : https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/42

I have searched for ages and can't find the setting to re-enable reporting. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided the link to the issue, but you didn't check the commit.

> Ardesco referenced this issue from a commit on Mar 12, 2012
>     #42 Reporting disabled by default due to the extreme amount of time it currently takes to build reports from large log files.
>   **2ca9e03**

Checking the commit 2ca9e03 you can see what's changed,

```
private boolean enableReports = false;
```

then track down where `enableReports` is set:

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/2ca9e033250e3990f583a0b6ebe9e3609155a6af/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/jmeter/configuration/ReportConfiguration.java#L80

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help from Will, and after some more digging, I eventually discovered that reporting was actually removed altogether from version 1.5.0 onwards

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/commit/7e1b42d0c669054df6827ab4f83a94409ed33122

To get reporting working, it is necessary to use a seperate plugin: jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin